# Installing Selenium webdriver error on OS X

Tags: python, selenium, pip

When installing Selenium using the following command line:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

I get the following warnings and errors:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'src_root'
  warnings.warn(msg)

warning: no files found matching 'docs/api/py/index.rst'
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium': Permission denied
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you don't have permission to write to the system Library.  Could you try with "sudo pip install -U selenium"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't have permission to write to the system Library. Could you try with "sudo pip install -U selenium"?

[moved from comments]

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled on the same problem. `pip install --user selenium` seems like a neater way to install the package, you can find more on the `--user` option over [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption--user)